# Why do I get a contradiction from $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X^2-\mu^2) }{N}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X-\mu)^2}{N}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

**I keep ending up in a contradiction with sigma notation, my confusion comes from the two standard deviation squared formulas.**

> [image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLrk2.jpg)

---

But going upwards $$\sigma^2=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X^2 }{N} -\frac{N\mu^2}{N}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X^2 -N\mu^2 }{N}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n \mu^2}{N}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X^2-\mu^2) }{N}$$
But of course but (1) which is my most trusted statement

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X^2-\mu^2) }{N}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X-\mu)^2}{N}$$
$\implies$ $$X^2-\mu^2=(X+\mu)(X-\mu)=(X-\mu)(X-\mu)$$
which is a trival contradiction so my problem is simply to see where I made my mistake

Comment: I had not quite seen it expressed that way, but consider $(1-4)(1+4)+(2-4)(2+4)+(9-4)(9+4) $ $=-15-12+65$ $=38$ $=9+4+25$ $=  (1-4)(1-4)+(2-4)(2-4)+(9-4)(9-4)$

Answer (score 5):

> $\frac{\sum (X^2-\mu^2) }{N}=\frac{\sum (X-\mu)^2}{N}\;\;$ $\implies$ $\;\;X^2-\mu^2=(X+\mu)(X-\mu)=(X-\mu)(X-\mu)$

This implication does not follow, and does not hold true in general. For two sums to match, it is not necessary that each term matches individually.

In this case:

$$
\sum \,(X-\mu)^2 \,=\, \sum \,(X^2-\mu^2)
$$

But:

$$
(X-\mu)^2 \,\ne\, X^2 - \mu^2
$$